# Getting two digits from a string in python with regex

Tags: python, regex, digit

I have multiple strings like this `90'4` I want to extract the digits from the string and sum them up to get 94.

I tried compiling the pattern.

```
pattern="\d'\d"
re.compile(pattern)
```

I tried the methods findall and match, but did not get what I wanted.

I need to use regex I cannot use .split()

Comment: Use `\d+` instead of `\d` if you want to capture multiple digit characters in a row

Comment: \d is ONE digit- now look at your pattern and your data - use http://www.regex101.com  to test it

Comment: Why don't you just split the string on `'`?

Comment: I am trying to get a regex solution, because I thinkg I wil need it in the future.

Comment: Does [Python: Extract numbers from a string](//stackoverflow.com/q/4289331) solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\d+` with `findall` to  extract numbers and then find their sum:

```
import re

s = "this is 90'4"

numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', s)
print(sum(map(int, numbers)))
# 94
```